# Как открыть файл через c#? (например .bat, или .vbs)

Tags: c#

В интернете я нашел вот такую функцию:
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad");`
И подумал можно ли сделать так с файлами .bat или .vbs?
Когда запускал выводились ошибки.
ПОМЕТОЧКА: Я ПОСТАВИЛ @ ПЕРЕД ПУТЁМ ПОЭТОМУ ПРОБЛЕМА НЕ В ЭТОМ.
Помогите пожайлуста.

Comment: Какие именно ошибки выводились?

Comment: Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred trying to start process '..\..\..\Новый точечный рисункок.bmp' with working directory 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\bin\Debug\net8.0'. Не удается найти указанный файл.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\Program.cs:line 1 в программе. сам дотнэт ошибок не выдаёт

Comment: Сами по себе файлы вы так открыть не можете. То, что вы кликаете по ним 2 раза и открывается нужный софт - это фишка OS, которая ассоциирует конкретный файл с конкретной программой. Для того, чтоб сделать подобное через код, который ничего про это не знает, вы должны явно указать программу, которая будет открывать нужный файл, в случае с блокнотом, это будет не `Process.Start("C:\\TextFile.txt")`, а `Process.Start("notepad \"C:\\TextFile.txt\"")` (указываем сначала путь к программе, а затем к самому файлу).

Comment: Что касается ошибки, то программа не может врать, если пишет файла по указанному пути нету, значит его там нету, проверяйте еще раз внимательно пути, и надеюсь вы понимаете, что такое `..\..`

Comment: Спасибо @EvgeniyZ

Comment: А как именно писать у меня выходит 2 ошибки неправильная escape-последовательность.

Comment: `"строка"`, в ней как видите есть двойные кавычки, чтоб написать там еще кавычки, их надо экранировать, написав перед ними косую черту, получите что-то вроде этого `"строка \" с кавычкой"`. Так, как косая черта это экранирующий символ, в случаях, когда он нам всеж нужен как символ, его также нужно экранировать, все той-же косой чертой не \ а \\ Также стоит учитывать пробелы в пути, если они есть, то путь целиком должен быть в кавычках. В итоге получаем путь по типу `C:\Folder\Супер файл.txt` будет таким `"\"C:\\Folder\\Супер файл.txt\""`

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"notepad \"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\aku.txt\""); примерно так?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174156/open-file-with-associated-application

Comment: Я наконец-то понял. `string path = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\aku.txt";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"notepad", path);`

Comment: Если используется `@`, то экранировать слеши не надо, достаточно одинарного. Вы и экранирование через `@` сделали, и сами экранировали, вот и ваша проблема с путями.

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\aku.vbs";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("wscript.exe", path);
```

Только вместо `path` - путь к программе.
А вместо `wscript.exe` - программа, которая должна открыть этот файл.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо теперь стало красивее.